# uwp TileContent with TileBackgroundImage does not work

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my `UWP` app I'm using two images to test the [HintOverLay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.tilepeekimage.hintoverlay?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) property with a background image. But the tile does not show the image or or the overlay of the image. I'm using the `Maps.xml` example of official [Notifications Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notifications-visualizer#:~:text=Overview,tile%20or%20toast%20notification%20payload.). Their example works fine on my system. But the following code does not:

**Question**: What I may be missing and how can we make it work. I've verified that the untitled3.png and untitled4.png exist in the `Assets/Apps/` folder. I'm using `VS2019 - ver16.6.2` on `Windows10 Pro -ver1903`?

**UPDATE**:

**Screenshot of Images junk1.png and junk2.png [size: 100x100 pixels]**

[image]

[image]

**Screenshot of Solution Explorer**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
.....
.....
TileContent content = new TileContent()
{
    Visual = new TileVisual()
    {
        TileMedium = new TileBinding()
        {
            Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
            {
                BackgroundImage = new TileBackgroundImage()
                {
                    Source = "Assets/Apps/junk1.png"
                },
                PeekImage = new TilePeekImage()
                {
                    Source = "Assets/Apps/junk2.jpg",
                    HintOverlay = 20
                }
            }
        },
        TileWide = new TileBinding()
        {
            Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
            {
                BackgroundImage = new TileBackgroundImage()
                {
                    Source = "Assets/Apps/junk1.png"
                },
                PeekImage = new TilePeekImage()
                {
                    Source = "Assets/Apps/junk2.png",
                    HintOverlay = 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// Create the tile notification
TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(content.GetXml());
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

// Send the notification to the primary tile
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```

Comment: Do you mean the tile didn't show the PeekImage you set? When I tested the above code, the PeekImage can be displayed well and added a 20% black overlay on it. I can't reproduce this issue. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Actually the file does not show at all. It shows just the default tile. I have added an **UPDATE** section so you can see the images and their sizes. The code is exactly the same as shown above. It is used in `MainPage.xaml.cs`. I see a relevant issue on `GitHub` [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/1110), as well.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT How can I can test my scenario in `Notifications Visualizer`?

Comment: I have checked it, but I still can't reproduce your issue, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? In addition, if you want to test your scenario in Notifications Visualizer, you need to convert c# code to xml like the Maps.xml example, but the image you can only use the Web picture or the image from Notifications Visualizer. If you directly use the Map.xml in your project, can it work well?